# LocationServices.GeofencingApi can't remove geofences

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-api-client, geofencing

In the app im writing I have to use GPS 6.1 (for your information) .
I'm adding geo fences using this code:

```
LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, normGeofences, pendingIntent);
```

and putting each requestId in shared preferences like this:

```
set.add(geofence.getRequestId());
```

saving the set:

```
sp.edit().putStringSet(ID_KEY, set).commit();
```

than the app closes. and in some point in time the user presses a notification that cancels the geo fences:

1. connect to googleApiClient:

   ```
   mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                      .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                      .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                      .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                      .build();

   mGoogleApiClient.connect();
   ```
2. after connected, removing geofences:

   ```
   public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

       Log.d(TAG, "Connected");
       insertGeoIds();
       // the method insertgeofences put the request ids in the List geoList
       if (mGeoList.size() > 0)
           LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, mGeoList);
   }
   ```

   - I have checked and the request ids are being loaded correctly.

**So, that's not working, the geofences keep being triggered.**

Answer (score 0):

1. It works fine for me so you have to be doing sth wrong - post more code.
2. Can you update GPS to latest?
3. Add callback which should be called when removing has succeed/failed like so:

```html
PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, mCurrentGeofenceIds);
pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(Status status) {
        onRemoveGeofencesByRequestIdsResult(status.getStatusCode());
    }
});
```